# How do I generate Facebook like button with only the FB page ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, sdk, facebook-like

So I have a database table with the Facebook page ID's of my users. I would like to generate a like button dynamically with only the ID available to me to do this. The problem as I see it is that I don't know what the `data-href` attribute is supposed to have considering that Facebook page url's look like this: `http://facebook.com/pages/hyphenated-name/<?=$FB_id?>` and I don't have the hyphenated name stored in my database to generate the that url.

Is there another URL structure Facebook's back-end will accept that just has the ID and not the hyphenated name, but will still count likes on that person's Facebook fan page? Is this impossible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a look up of the id, and retrieve the link of the page stored.

example: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=191825050853209

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/ under link connection.

This method will require use of the graph api, or one of the sdks.

refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api

Comment: That's genius. I wish I had thought of that.